# R Categorical Variable Orders for plotting

Tags: r, variables

[On the right hand side is the current order of the categorical variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo698.png)

I'm trying to change the order so "Charged Off" and "Default" is at the bottom while the rest of them remains unchanged. I can't seem to get either reorder or relevel to work. Most of the time I get the error

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "post09$LoanStatus <- relevel(post09$LoanStatus, ref = c("Cancelled", Completed", ""
```

Comment: Maybe "Completed"? Seems you're missing a " .

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works -

```
data <- factor(letters[1:10])
data1 <- c("i","j",setdiff(data,c("i","j")))
data_reordered <- factor(data1, levels=data1)
```

If not, please share some more info regarding your question along with a reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed what has level must already be factors, but turned out you can have levels without being a factor.

I fixed it simply using

```
post09$LoanStatus <- factor(post09$LoanStatus, levels = c("Completed", "FinalPaymentInProgress", "Current", "Past Due (1-15 days)", "Past Due (16-30 days)", "Past Due (31-60 days)", "Past Due (61-90 days)", "Past Due (91-120 days)", "Past Due (>120 days)", "Chargedoff", "Defaulted"))
```

Comment: In the future, if you share your data with `dput()` or summarize its structure with `str()`, it's classes will be obvious which makes it easier to solve problems. `ggplot` will silently convert `character` vectors to `factor`s. Perhaps this is what you mean by "you can have levels without being a factor"?